# Why Reboot Spider-Man?

Tags: the-amazing-spider-man, spider-man-trilogy, reboot

I can understand the reboot of the Batman Series but I couldn't understand why Hulk was rebooted. And now why do we have to reboot Spider-Man, too?

Is it they are not able to write the script in the same back-drop as the previous movies in the series? Is it because they are not able to write sequels or prequels that will not conflict with the story already told in the previous movies?

Comment: This is a Rhetorical question and as such, meets the site definition of ***not a real question*** It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or ***rhetorical*** and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. For help clarifying this question so that it can be reopened, see the FAQ.

Comment: I honestly think this is a good question.  I did a little digging and found that Spider Man 4 was planned, but was scrapped in order to do the reboot.  I wasn't able to find any prevelant information as to **why** SM4 was cancelled.

Comment: I think this could be a good question, if it's cleaned up to focus specifically on Spider-Man, and not reboots in general.

Comment: See [this article](http://www.cinemablend.com/new/Why-Spider-Man-Absolutely-Needed-Reboot-31610.html?utm_source=zergnet.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=zergnet_25270).

Comment: Far as I'm able to tell (mostly from conjecture on The Internet) is that it's down to the licencing deal that Sony  have with Marvel Studios. It's the same reason why Spidey wasn't in Avengers... Again, conjecture on The Internet is my basis for this comment

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [**Deadline - 'Spider-Man 4'′ scrapped**](http://www.deadline.com/2010/01/urgent-spider-man-4-scrapped-as-is-raimi-and-cast-out-franchise-reboot-planned/): (January 2010)

> [...] **Sony Pictures decided today to reboot the Spider-Man franchise after franchise director Sam Raimi pulled out of Spider-Man 4 because he felt he couldn’t make its summer release date and keep the film’s creative integrity.**
>
> [...] My sources tell me that Raimi told Sony Pictures: “*I can’t make your date. I can’t go forward creatively.*” And, so, once he said “*That’s it*”, Sony Pictures co-chairman Amy Pascal and Columbia Pictures’ Matt Tolmach decided they didn’t want to replace him and instead chose to reboot the franchise.
>
> [...] The events that led to today’s shocking decision to scrap Spider-Man 4 can be traced to mid-December when I saw a December 11th email alerting the pic’s special effects crew that the fourquel would not be starting as planned ”*but Sam Raimi has story issues [that] need to be resolved before we are ready to shoot*”.
>
> At that point, it wasn’t well known that the Spider-Man franchise director helming the 4th installment had huge problems with the script that has run through screenwriters Jamie Vanderbilt, David Lindsay-Abaire, and Gary Ross. I was told Sam Raimi had been very vocal inside Sony that he “hated” it.

(click the link to read the Sony's official press release)

Comment: "...keep the film’s creative integrity" BA HA HA HA HA!... Sorry.

Comment: Isn't also another reason, is if Sony do not continue making Spider-Man movies they lose the rights to the Spider-Man IP? I don't have sources for that, but probably read some where from other SE questions.

Answer (score 3):

The reason behind [The Hulk's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hulk_%28film%29) reboot is the negative reviews of the film (It's a different fact that some of people like me liked the old Hulk movie more). And the new Hulk film is also made up his entry in Marvel cinematic universe.

For case of Spider-man Sony and Rami's Clashes are the reason for cancelling Spider-man 4 and then Sony decided for a reboot to save the lose of copyrights of spider-man films. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_in_film#Spider-Man_4) for details.