# Why are they rebooting/reviving The Matrix franchise?

Tags: the-matrix, reboot

I heard that The Matrix is being [*rebooted/revived*](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/heat-vision/matrix-reboot-works-at-warner-bros-986292). What are the reasons they chose to do this instead of making a sequel or prequel?

Is there any **official** word on Why the production company or anyone else wants to do this?

I am asking for confirmed sources/facts - **no opinions please**.
I am not complaining about this, I just want to know why in this case the production company thought a reboot was the right choice at this time and not a sequel, prequel or a different story in the same world.

Comment: Money I guess? Also, while it has good CGI for its time, they have been quite improved. Also, we are now more "technology user" now, so it may be a little changed and updated to now.

Comment: In addition: Writers [say](http://www.ign.com/articles/2017/03/17/new-matrix-movie-writer-says-its-not-a-reboot), it is NOT a reboot...

Comment: Re-edited the question to make it clear that the OP is asking for **official** sources only. If this is not what you are after, please feel free to re-edit to something more suitable.

Comment: That scene where Neo fights an army of Agent Smith's in the courtyard is HORRIBLY CGI'd.  I'd be OK if they just re-did that movie with updated technology.  That being said, it seems like Hollywood is out of ideas.  Everything is getting remade sooner or later, sometimes twice.  Every studio is looking to piggyback on something proven to draw fans.  It's a low-risk, high-reward proposition.

Comment: @JohnnyBones totally agree. Hollywood seems to be out of ideas.

Comment: I predict a commercial and critical failure if this is true.

Comment: I really don't understand why this question is ok and mine isn't https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/3179/why-reboot-spiderman?rq=1

Comment: @papakias - The question linked is open and has received positive votes.  What makes you think it's not OK?  Although, in truth, your question sounds more like a complaint, whereas this one is worded more like an actual question.  And if that really is your question, why do you have two different accounts?  They should be merged, in accordance with StackExchange guidelines.

Comment: @JohnnyBones I Think the question I linked is ok. And so is mine!

Comment: Ahh.  OK, I misunderstood.  Yeah, I think yours is actually better worded, not sure why it got downvoted.

Comment: @I re-edited it! Hope it seems good this time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an answer in the article:

> While some at Warners consider the title among the studio's sacrosanct
>   properties, like Casablanca, others see a need to redevelop it in an
>   environment where studios are desperately looking for ways to monetize
>   their libraries and branded IP is hard to come by.

Basically, they are looking to make more money of an already successful franchise to which they own the rights.

> But Warner Bros. sees a model in what Disney and Lucasfilm have done
>   with Star Wars, exploring the hidden corners of the universe with
>   movies such as Rogue One: A Star Wars Story...Perhaps a young Morpheus
>   movie could come out of the exploration, as an example.

It could be that they explore different characters, but there's no official word on what it is going to be, but it is unlikely to feature Keanu Reeves:

> While promoting John Wick: Chapter 2, Reeves said he would be open to
>   returning for another installment of the franchise if the Wachowskis
>   were involved. "They would have to write it and direct it. And then
>   we'd see what the story is, but yeah, I dunno, that'd be weird, but
>   why not?" he told Yahoo Movies. However, it is likely that Warners
>   will look elsewhere to attract an A-list director and star.